# Computing time difference from logfile entries

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have two fields in logs sending time and received time mentioned in milliseconds, I have to find difference between these two fields, if it's greater than 2 seconds print those logs using shell script or Linux commands.

```
2017-01-27 object1(sendtime-1486743904359 ,recdtime-  1486743904500)
2017-01-27 object2(sendtime-1486743904800 ,recdtime-  1486743908000)
```

my log files contains other lines also, which i need filter out based on above send/received time  condition and only  logs which contains "sendobject" keyword. Others like request sent, request received should be ignored

Log Details--

```
2017-01-27 [Info]Delta Cache sendobject (empId-emp1, joindate-456,dealdate-123,sendtime-1527348020000 ,recdtime-1527348028000, salary-1k,amtpaid-EUR)
2017-01-27 [Info]Delta Cache sendobject (empId-emp2, joindate-456,dealdate-123,sendtime-1527348073000 ,recdtime-1527348074000, salary-1k,amtpaid-AUD)
2017-01-27 [Info]Requestsent| (empId-emp1, joindate-456,dealdate-123,sendtime-1527352812000 ,recdtime-1527352820000, salary-1k,amtpaid-INR)
2017-01-27 [Info]Delta Cache sendobject (empId-emp3, joindate-456,dealdate-123,sendtime-1527349111000 ,recdtime-1527349112000, salary-1k,amtpaid-GBP)
2017-01-27 [Info]Delta Cache sendobject (empId-emp4, joindate-456,dealdate-123,sendtime-1527349370000 ,recdtime-1527349375000, salary-1k,amtpaid-CAD)
2017-01-27 [Info]Requestrecicved| (empId-emp1, joindate-456,dealdate-123,sendtime-1527352812000 ,recdtime-1527352820000, salary-1k,amtpaid-INR)
2017-01-27 [Info]Delta Cache sendobject (empId-emp6, joindate-456,dealdate-123,sendtime-1527352812000 ,recdtime-1527352820000, salary-1k,amtpaid-INR)
2017-01-27 [Info]DBupdated| (empId-emp1, joindate-456,dealdate-123,sendtime-1527352812000 ,recdtime-1527352820000, salary-1k,amtpaid-INR)
```

Comment: Is there any specific time for sendtime and recdtime ?

Comment: The first set of example lines you gave (containing "object1" & "object2") and the ones mentioned later under "Log Details--" have very different format. You need to fix the format.

Comment: answer edited.-

Comment: Later updated logs are final one..

Answer (score 2):

With `awk` you can do like:

```
awk -F"[- ,)]" '$(NF-1)-$5 >2000' infile
2017-01-27 object2(sendtime-1486743904800 ,recdtime-  1486743908000)
```

Here we defines sets of *hyphen, space, comma and close parenthesis* as fields separators.

**to answer the revised question, try:**

```
awk -F"[- ,]" '/sendobject/ && $18-$15 >2000' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

A variant on [@αғsнιη's answer](/a/444302):

```
awk -F'(sen|rec)dtime-' 'NF==3 && $3 - $2 > 2000'
```

Or, if the logs contain all sorts of lines beside these ones, you could be even more restrictive in matching the input with `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'print if m{
    ^\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d\s+
    object\d+\(
       sendtime-(\d+)\s*,
       recdtime-\s*(\d+)
    \)$}x && $2 - $1 > 2000'
```